# uservoice for iphone, anything formatted directly for iphone screen?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know of a site similar to [uservoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219112537/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/) that provides a iphone specific web front end?

The plan is that there will be a link in my iphone app for user feedback and this will open mobile safari at the uservoice or similar site?

That is, a bug tracker with iphone/mobile safari tweaks?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder, what is wrong in using UserVoice in the iPhone? It's quite readable and the everyone knows how to use it :)

[alt text http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/6899/photoxxz.jpg](http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/6899/photoxxz.jpg)

Comment: I agree, just looking for something targetted directly at the iphone, but guess there is nothing ... yet.  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I heard Crittercism (http://www.crittercism.com/) works pretty well and it's free.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/), even though it is paid, you can get a [free licence for individual or Open Source Project](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/licensing.jsp#nonprofit). 
the iPhone app is developed by [Shaun Ervine](http://www.apptism.com/developers/shaun-ervine), and it costs $8.99. Also there is a project by [Daniel Dickison](http://danieldickison.com/), for a Bugzilla app, but it is still raw.

I would have to mention, i haven't tried Jira yet (GIT fan here), but seems good, althought a bit expensive.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a web based solution - something I can link to/jump to from my iphone app - will update my question...thanks.